# Positioning the 3D axes

Tags: 3d

How to position the 3D axes besides the centre of the screen?

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
% The axes
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:x=1.5) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:y=1.5) node[right] {$z$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:z=1.5) node[above] {$y$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

The axes appear at the centre.  How do I position it on left or right of screen?

Comment: In your previous posts you were able to present complete MWEs, i.e. documents that start with `\documentclass` and ended with `\end{document}`. What happened to that ability? And you'd greatly benefit from explaining what "centre of the screen" means.

Comment: Completed in the obvious way, those axes will appear on the left. So presumably you're completing it in some non-obvious way we-know-not-what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to move the axis. Ti*k*Z of course trims the picture. But if you put `\path (coordinate);` with some suitable coordinate there will be space to the left, to the right, above and/or below the axes, depending on your choice of `(coordinate)`. Here are two examples, which are, by relativity, equivalent.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% The axes
\path(0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:x=1.5) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:y=1.5) node[right] {$z$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:z=1.5) node[above] {$y$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% The axes
\path(-3,0);
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:x=1.5) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:y=1.5) node[right] {$z$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=-1.5) -- (xyz cs:z=1.5) node[above] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]